# find the img id and src and adding to the array

Tags: javascript

Heres my html code:

```
<div id="cmdt_1_29d" class="dt_state2" onclick="sel_test(this.id)">
    <img id="cmdt_1_29i" onclick="dropit('cmdt_1_29');"
         src="http://hitechpackaging.zes.zeald.com/interchange-5/en_US/ico_minus.png">
    <span class="dt_link">
        <a href="javascript://">CARTON &amp; BOARD</a>
    </span> 
</div> 
<div id="cmdt_2_31d" class="dt_istate1" onclick="sel_test(this.id)">
    <img src="/site/hitechpackaging/images/items/test.jpb ">
    <a href="https://secure.zeald.com/hitechpackaging/shop/CARTON%20%20%20%20BOARD/CORRUGATED%20%20CORNER%20BOARD?mv_pc=21497">CORRUGATED &amp; CORNER BOARD</a>
</div>
```

The dropit function modifies my img src which I dont want to, unfortunately I cant modify,
Can I somehow read the data into array before it is being modified and that I can add the data back to the image.

Comment: [Indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation) is good.

Comment: Your post doesn't make sense. Can you please post some more information on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the click handler:

```
var i = document.getElementById('cmd1_1_29i');
i.onclick = null;
```

Or, if you want to still call the original click handler:

```
var i = document.getElementById('cmd1_1_29i');
_onclick = i.onclick;

i.onclick = function(e) {
    // do what you want here
    _onclick && _onclick.apply(this, [e]);
}
​
```